# Choosing right value of m in SARIMA models

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality

If I'm trying to avoid Auto-Arima function, is their any handy table/reference list which I can refer to for knowing what value of `m` to choose for working with `SARIMA(p, d, q)(P, D, Q)m` model?

Or, is these collation of values from different sources right?

- Daily data m=7,
- Weekly data m=53,
- Monthly data m=12,
- Quarterly data m=4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic ARIMA fitting methods require the seasonal order as an input, they don't *choose* or *fit* $m$, so I'm not quite sure why you think avoiding `auto.arima` has anything to do with the choice of $m$.

The season length $m$ is the number of periods after which you expect a pattern to repeat. It does not necessarily have anything to do with your time granularity.

- Daily data can have $m=7$ (weekly seasonality), $m=14$ (biweekly seasonality, e.g., paycheck effects in locales where salaries are paid out every two weeks), $m\approx 30$ or $31$ (monthly seasonality), or $m\approx 365$ (yearly seasonality).
- Weekly data can have $m=2$ (biweekly seasonality), $m=4$ (four-weekly seasonality), or $m\approx 53$ (yearly seasonality).
- Monthly data can have $m=3$ (quarterly seasonality) or $m=12$ (yearly seasonality).
- Quarterly data can have $m=4$ (yearly seasonality).

In all these cases, many other values of $m$ are possible. If you want to model quarterly approval ratings of US presidents, you may want to use $m=16$ (four years in office, four quarters each). Your choice of $m$ should be governed by your use case.

Note that ARIMA has a hard time dealing with [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities).